# Building the FBX SDK on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu, gcc4, fbx

Trying to get one of the samples compiled on Ubuntu 12.04

I’m using
`make -f Makefile-x64-static`

However, I get the error
`make: gcc4: Command not found`

I tried switching from gcc4 to gcc in the makefile.

However, I get the compile errors
`note: #pragma message: IMPORTANT NOTE: The FBX SDK API changed substantially. Please define FBXSDK_NEW_API in your project and fix compilation errors as instructed in fbxsdk_compatibility.h.`

And the link error
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -luuid`

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pre-requisites

> sudo apt-get install uuid-dev
>
> sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev libxi-dev
>
> sudo apt-get install libx11-dev

## Makefile modifications required

Change gcc4 to gcc

> CC = gcc
>
> LD = gcc

add -lX11 to LIBS

> LIBS = -lfbxsdk-$(LIBFBXVERSION)$(STATIC) -lm -lrt -luuid -lc -lstdc++ -lpthread -ldl -lglut_gcc34-amd64 -lGLEW_amd64 -lGLU -lGL -lXmu -lX11

add -DFBXSDK_NEW_API to C_FLAGS and CXX_FLAGS

> CFLAGS = -m64 -DFBXSDK_NEW_API
>
> CXXFLAGS = -m64 -DFBXSDK_NEW_API